# UIDatePicker: Has a date and time option, but how to display both in an app?

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepicker

**EDIT:** For future reference: found this for NSDateFormatter. This documentation shows the different code to display the proper date and time format you are looking for. Cheers.

http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/

I am creating an app that uses a UIDatePicker to select a date AND time for an event (there is an option for this in the storyboard).

I want to know how I can display both the date AND the time in a label after selection/save. Right now, this is what I have for portions of my code throughout my app. My question is: do I change the formatter code to allow the UIDatePicker to display the date AND time in my app? Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

MasterViewController

```
    -(void)configureCell:(MasterEventCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    }

    Event *eventAtIndex = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.eventDetailsLabel.text = eventAtIndex.detail;
    cell.eventLocationLabel.text = eventAtIndex.location;
    cell.eventDateTimeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)eventAtIndex.date];

}
```

DetailViewController

```
    - (void)configureView
{
    Event *theEvent = self.event;

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    }
    if (theEvent) {
        self.detailLabel.text = theEvent.detail;
        self.locationLabel.text = theEvent.location;
        self.dateTimeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)theEvent.date];
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, put the date and time in a label?  If you just want to display you don't need a picker, and NSDateFormatter will format date and time any way you want.

Comment: I am letting the user select a date and time, then am displaying their choice in a table view cell (along with some other information they select). I simply want to know how to manipulate the formatter code in order to allow the display of both date and time, as of right now, I only see the display of a date after a user enters information.

Comment: Use a formatter set to display both date and time.  (This implies, among other things, actually reading the documentation for NSDateFormatter.)

Comment: Already took a peek at that documentation, and some of it is a bit ambiguous for specific formatting for the date and time. Figured out what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `setTimeStyle:` too on the date formatter.

Comment: Awesome! I knew it had to be something like adding that. Thanks!